# Longest word made from a chemical molecule?

Tags: word, chemistry

I was wearing my [Bacon t-shirt](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00644O9DA), and got to wondering, what's the longest word made solely with the atomic symbols of every atom in a compound?

For example, ${CO_{2}}$ would be coo, since there are two ${O}$ atoms.

Comment: This reminds me of my favorite wikipedia page: [List of chemical compounds with unusual names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_compounds_with_unusual_names)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible eight is

> **Choo-choo** a childish name for a locomotive which chemically is oxalic acid ${C_{2}H_{2}}O_{4}$

Comment: But then you need to rearrange `CCHHOOOO` which my dictionary tells me isn't a word.

Comment: OP has said in another comment that anagrams are fine, so I think this would be allowed.

Comment: I thought per HeliumRubidium's comment that anagrams are OxygenPotassium.

Answer (score 5):

A possible six (without anagramming):

> **Co<sub>2</sub>As**, whose existence I think can be confirmed by [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022508891903617), becomes **cocoas**.

Answer (score 3):

I have found 1 five:

> sodium monosulfide - **Na<sub>2</sub>S** - NANAS (5)

And lots of fours. Here are just some:

> dicobalt phosphide - **CO**<sub>**2**</sub>**P** - COOP (4)
> barium fluoride - **BaF<sub>2</sub>** - BAFF (4)
> barium selenide - **BaSe** - BASE (4)
> calcium selenide - **CaSe** - CASE (4)
> copper (II) fluoride - **CuF<sub>2</sub>** - CUFF (4)
> copper (II) telluride - **CuTe** - CUTE (4)
> gallium (II) telluride - **GaTe** - GATE (4)
> molybdenum sulfide - **MoS<sub>2</sub>** - MOSS (4)

Can't find anything longer than five...

I believe I have reached the Fluorine Iodine Nitrogen Iodine Sulfur Hydrogen

Answer (score 1):

We need a real chemist to determine what's actually possible, I think. But I have a plausible 6:

> `H
>       /
>  O==Te
>       \
>        Cl`

would yield

> CLOTHE.

[EDITED to add: No, duh, that won't do because I'm splitting up the letters of a chemical symbol and that isn't allowed. Thanks to Beastly Gerbil for pointing that out in comments. I'm leaving this here in case anything in it turns out to be useful to others.]

Does that compound exist? I don't see why not. If you take a look at

> the box at top right of [the Wikipedia page on organotellurium chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organotellurium_chemistry) you'll see a similar structure with an arbitrary hydrocarbon radical in place of the chlorine. In ordinary organic chemistry one can commonly substitute a halogen for a hydrocarbon radical, and looking at the various halides also present in that box it seems like the same is true with tellurium. Note also that the corresponding compound with carbon in the middle is [formyl chloride](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Formyl_chloride) which definitely exists.

But I'm not a chemist and maybe I'm making illegitimate analogies here.

Comment: I think that placing H between T and e would be against the rules, as Te is 1 element, not 2. Also as far as I am aware the word has to be in the order the formula appears, you can't anagram.

Comment: Ohhh, you're definitely right about not being able to split the Te. I missed that. As for order matching the formula, though, I don't see any such requirement in the question and the order of things in a formula is often pretty arbitrary.

Comment: Hmm, “arbitrary”?  Well, not so much.  IUPAC does conventionally establish standards which are rather formal and thorough.

Comment: Anagrams are fine, but splitting the Te would not be.

Answer (score 1):

I **MAY** have a 10 if you'll allow 1) a hyphenated word with 2) an extra, unnecessary character on the end...

> [image]
>
> ...and 3) a complete disregard for science!